# Is there an equivalent of canvas's toDataURL method for SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

I am trying to load an svg image into canvas for pixel manipulation
I need a method like `toDataURL` or `getImageData` for svg

on Chrome/Safari I can try doing it through and image and canvas

```
var img = new Image()
img.onload = function(){
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0) //this correctly draws the svg image to the canvas! however...
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(); //SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18
  var data = ctx.getImageData(0,0,img.width, img.height).data //also SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18
  }
  img.src = "image.svg" //that is an svg file. (same domain as html file :))
```

But I get security errors. 
Any other way?

Here is a live demo of the problem http://clstff.appspot.com/gist/462846 (you can view source)

Comment: Is the SVG image coming from a different domain? If it is, you can't call `toDataURL` or `getImageData` because the canvas isn't "origin-clean" anymore.

Comment: It is coming from the *same* domain. I even tried doing `img.src = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,..."` but that also didn't work

Comment: This seems to be a bug in Webkit: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39059

Comment: I looked at that bug. It says the problem is with `drawImage`. For me, `drawImage` works. It's the `toDataURL` or `getImageData` that doesn't work after I draw the image.

Comment: Have you tried using fabric.js to load SVG onto canvas, then get dataurl image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From: http://www.svgopen.org/2009/papers/12-Using_Canvas_in_SVG/#d4e105

> The reason why you cannot use an SVG
>   image element as source for the
>   drawImage method is simple, but
>   painful: the current Canvas
>   specification does not (yet) allow to
>   reference SVGImageElement as source
>   for drawImage and can only cope with
>   HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement
>   and HTMLVideoelement. This
>   short-coming will hopefully be
>   addressed during the process of
>   defining "SVG in HTML5" behavior and
>   could be extended to allow
>   SVGSVGElement as well. The xhtml:img
>   element in listing 3 uses
>   visibility:hidden as we do not want it
>   to interfere with its visible copy on
>   the Canvas.

Answer (score 14):

```
var dataUrl = 'data:image/svg+xml,'+encodeURIComponent(svgString);
```

Comment: svgString means?

Comment: var svgString = document.getElementById("svg_element_id").outerHTML

Comment: @Eugenio: and if that doesn't work, do var svgString = outerXHTML(document.getElementById("svg_element_id")) with the function outerXHTML from my answer. The "standard" `.outerHTML` is lacking the namespace attribute, if you created the node programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can't do that directly, but you can use [canvg](http://code.google.com/p/canvg/) for that, I mean, to draw SVG to Canvas, and get data url from Canvas. It's not without bugs, especially for complex gradients processing, but I had some positive experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

Illustrating Hubert OG 's answer with code; 2 remarks first.

First (thank you, Robert Longson), it might work without encodeURIComponent, but you better include it (for example, if you have something like `fill="url(#pattern)"` the encodeURIComponent is necessary, because of the # character)

Second, the SVG namespace is *not* optional, but it might not be included in `svgElt.outerHTML`. Especially, if you have created your svg node via `createElementNS`, like so

```
svgElt = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'svg')
```

then a subsequent call to `svgElt.outerHTML` *will not* contain the namespace attribute, and this would result in not working code, unless you include the namespace attribute later in some fashion

```js
var imgEnc    = new Image();
var imgEncNS  = new Image();
var prefix    = 'data:image/svg+xml,';
var svgOpen   = '<svg width="200" height="30">';
var svgClose  = '</svg>';
var svgOpenNS = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="30">';
var rect      = '<rect width="200" height="30" fill="black"/>';
var html      = svgOpen + rect + svgClose;
var htmlNS    = svgOpenNS + rect + svgClose;
var htmlEnc   = window.encodeURIComponent(html);
var htmlEncNS = window.encodeURIComponent(htmlNS);
imgEnc.src   = prefix + htmlEnc;
imgEncNS.src = prefix + htmlEncNS;
function T(txt){
  document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txt));
}
function HR(){ document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('hr')); }
function BR(){ document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br')); }
function A(arg){ document.body.appendChild(arg); }
T('without namespace'); BR(); A(imgEnc); HR();
T('with namespace'); BR(); A(imgEncNS);
```

you can fix the missing namespace issue by using function `outerXHTML` from my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057842/how-do-i-convert-html-to-xhtml-using-javascript/)

or like this

```
function imgFromSVGnode(node){
    function setNS(elt, parentNS){
        var namespace = elt.namespaceURI;
        if (namespace!==parentNS){
            elt.setAttribute('xmlns', namespace);
        }
        for (var i=0; i<elt.childNodes.length; i++){
            setNS(elt.childNodes[i], namespace);
        }
    }
    setNS(node, null);
    var html = node.outerHTML;
    var dataURL = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + window.encodeURIComponent(html);
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = dataURL;
    return img;
};
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62109331/namespace-attributes-not-present-in-outerhtml

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227612/how-to-create-document-objects-with-javascript

Comment: The question you answered **was** caused by very early implementations of the canvas API, when svg images were not yet accepted as source-image. There is no real reasons anyone would face this issue today. You were probably looking for https://stackoverflow.com/q/27230293/3702797 instead.

Answer (score -1):

first download a js library svg_todataurl.js and include it

then just paste this code

```
var SVGtopngDataURL = document.getElementById("svg_element_id").toDataURL("image/png");
```