# Convert SVG to image (JPEG, PNG, etc.) in the browser

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to convert SVG into bitmap images (like JPEG, PNG, etc.) through JavaScript.

Comment: What task is it that you actually want to accomplish? Even though echo-flows answer tell us that it is (in some browsers) possible there are better and easier conversion methods for almost all practical cases.

Comment: Here's an example using d3: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23667012/439699

Comment: http://svgopen.org/2010/papers/62-From_SVG_to_Canvas_and_Back/ - Works perfectly! [On the link page, sourceSVG = $("#your_svg_elem_name").get(0) ]

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173048/is-there-an-equivalent-of-canvass-todataurl-method-for-svg

Comment: https://mybyways.com/blog/convert-svg-to-png-using-your-browser

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capture HTML Canvas as gif/jpg/png/pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf)

Comment: Try https://www.sitelint.com/blog/convert-svg-to-png-or-jpg-or-webp-with-javascript/

Answer (score 283, accepted):

Here is how you can do it through JavaScript:

1. Use the canvg JavaScript library to render the SVG image using Canvas: https://github.com/gabelerner/canvg
2. Capture a data URI encoded as a JPG (or PNG) from the Canvas, according to these instructions: [Capture HTML Canvas as gif/jpg/png/pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf/3514404#3514404)

Comment: This isn't strictly Javascript, but HTML5 as well. This will not work on IE8, or any other browser that does not support HTML5 Canvas.

Comment: Thanks for not supporting IE8. People should understand that it's time to move on.

Comment: You can now use the JavaScript SVG library [Pablo](http://pablojs.com) to achieve this (I made it). See the [`toImage()`](http://pablojs.com/api/toImage/) and also [`download()`](http://pablojs.com/api/download/) for an auto-downloaded image.

Comment: @Premasagar how did you do this? All I can get is empty svg file

Comment: canvg is incomplete. e.g. it doesn't support masks.

Comment: @Premasagar Unfortunately the link doesn't work, but your comment sounds very interesting.

Comment: @daniel is right. this solutions doesn't work with masks. did you get with solution with masks?

Comment: Note that in late 2022 (and beyond) step 1 is entirely unnecessary. Just draw the SVG onto a canvas, no third party libraries required, then use `toDataURL`.

Answer (score 48):

jbeard4 solution worked beautifully.

I'm using [Raphael SketchPad](http://ianli.com/sketchpad/) to create an SVG.  Link to the files in step 1.

For a Save button (id of svg is "editor", id of canvas is "canvas"):

```
$("#editor_save").click(function() {

// the canvg call that takes the svg xml and converts it to a canvas
canvg('canvas', $("#editor").html());

// the canvas calls to output a png
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
// do what you want with the base64, write to screen, post to server, etc...
});
```

Comment: canvg need the second parameter to be `<svg>...</svg` but jquery html() function don't add svg tag, so this code works for me but I needed to edit the canvg live to `canvg('canvas', '<svg>'+$("#editor").html()+'</svg>');`

Comment: @Luckyn if you call `$(selector).html()` on the parent of your *svg* element, it will work

Comment: @Luckyn and @jonathanGB, you shouldn't have to use `html()` on wrappers, or manually construct the parent `svg` tag -- which might even have attributes you leave out with this hack. Just use `$(svg_elem)[0].outerHTML` gives you the full source of the svg and its contents. Just saying...

Answer (score 36):

This seems to work in most browsers:

```
function copyStylesInline(destinationNode, sourceNode) {
   var containerElements = ["svg","g"];
   for (var cd = 0; cd < destinationNode.childNodes.length; cd++) {
       var child = destinationNode.childNodes[cd];
       if (containerElements.indexOf(child.tagName) != -1) {
            copyStylesInline(child, sourceNode.childNodes[cd]);
            continue;
       }
       var style = sourceNode.childNodes[cd].currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(sourceNode.childNodes[cd]);
       if (style == "undefined" || style == null) continue;
       for (var st = 0; st < style.length; st++){
            child.style.setProperty(style[st], style.getPropertyValue(style[st]));
       }
   }
}

function triggerDownload (imgURI, fileName) {
  var evt = new MouseEvent("click", {
    view: window,
    bubbles: false,
    cancelable: true
  });
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.setAttribute("download", fileName);
  a.setAttribute("href", imgURI);
  a.setAttribute("target", '_blank');
  a.dispatchEvent(evt);
}

function downloadSvg(svg, fileName) {
  var copy = svg.cloneNode(true);
  copyStylesInline(copy, svg);
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  var bbox = svg.getBBox();
  canvas.width = bbox.width;
  canvas.height = bbox.height;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, bbox.width, bbox.height);
  var data = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(copy);
  var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
  var img = new Image();
  var svgBlob = new Blob([data], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
  var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);
  img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    if (typeof navigator !== "undefined" && navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob)
    {
        var blob = canvas.msToBlob();         
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
    } 
    else {
        var imgURI = canvas
            .toDataURL("image/png")
            .replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
        triggerDownload(imgURI, fileName);
    }
    document.removeChild(canvas);
  };
  img.src = url;
}
```

Comment: This is not working in IE11, because of the security issue with `.msToBlob()`

Comment: Thanks!! I love how this works for both a "local" SVG HTML node and a remote SVG URL. Plus it doesn't require a full external library

Comment: Could you provide a usage example?

Comment: This copyStylesInline helped me a lot!! Without adding that, my exported png was looking very weird. Thank you!

Comment: I have an issue with using SVGAnimateElement (since animations do not affect the style of the SVG), did someone else encounter it?

Answer (score 34):

The solution to convert SVG to blob URL and blob URL to png image

```js
const svg=`<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="300" height="200"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
   <circle cx="150" cy="100" r="80" fill="green" />
   <text x="150" y="125" font-size="60" text-anchor="middle" fill="white">SVG</text></svg>`
svgToPng(svg,(imgData)=>{
    const pngImage = document.createElement('img');
    document.body.appendChild(pngImage);
    pngImage.src=imgData;
});
 function svgToPng(svg, callback) {
    const url = getSvgUrl(svg);
    svgUrlToPng(url, (imgData) => {
        callback(imgData);
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    });
}
function getSvgUrl(svg) {
    return  URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([svg], { type: 'image/svg+xml' }));
}
function svgUrlToPng(svgUrl, callback) {
    const svgImage = document.createElement('img');
    // imgPreview.style.position = 'absolute';
    // imgPreview.style.top = '-9999px';
    document.body.appendChild(svgImage);
    svgImage.onload = function () {
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = svgImage.clientWidth;
        canvas.height = svgImage.clientHeight;
        const canvasCtx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvasCtx.drawImage(svgImage, 0, 0);
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        callback(imgData);
        // document.body.removeChild(imgPreview);
    };
    svgImage.src = svgUrl;
 }
```

Comment: This solution does not work for complex SVG (e.g. patterns with images)

Comment: Here is your code but optimized, but thank you for that...
https://codepen.io/arcaelas-the-looper/pen/wvrqzvm

Comment: Thanks you @AlejandroReyes

Comment: You are welcome, u can followme in github: arcaelas

Comment: For some reason, when I used `URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([svg], { type: 'image/svg+xml' }))`, some SVGs got tainted (I suspect it has todo with that they have \<style\>s defined in them), but then I tried creating data urls from scratch like so:  `'data:image/svg+xml;utf-8,${svg.replace(/#/g, '%23').replace(/\n/g, '%0A')}';`, which worked flawlessly! You could also use base64 like this: `'data:image/svg+xml;base64,${btoa(drawing)}';`. I am using electron

Answer (score 34):

This is an old question, in 2022 we have ES6 and we don't need 3rd party libraries.

Here is a very basic way to convert `svg` images into other formats.

The trick is to load the `svg` element as an `img` element, then use a canvas element to convert the image into the desired format. So, four steps are needed:

1. Extract `svg` as `xml` data string.
2. Load the `xml` data string into a `img` element
3. Convert the `img` element to a `dataURL` using a `canvas` element
4. Load the converted `dataURL` into a new `img` element

#### Step 1

Extracting a `svg` as `xml` data string is simple, we don't need to convert it as a base64 string. We just serialize it as XML then we encode the string as a URI:

```js
// Data header for a svg image: 
const dataHeader = 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'

// Serialize it as xml string:
const serializeAsXML = $e => (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString($e)

// Encode URI data as UTF8 data:
const encodeAsUTF8 = s => `${dataHeader},${encodeURIComponent(s)}`

// Select the element:
const $svg = document.getElementById('svg-container').querySelector('svg')

// Encode it as a data string:
const svgData = encodeAsUTF8(serializeAsXML($svg))
```

##### Note:

If you need a base64 data you can use this option:

```js
...

// Encode URI data as base64 data:
const encodeAsB64 = s => `${dataHeader};base64,${btoa(s)}`
...

// Encode it as a data string:
const svgData = encodeAsB64(serializeAsXML($svg))
```

#### Step 2

Loading the `xml` data string into a `img` element:

```js
// This function returns a Promise whenever the $img is loaded
const loadImage = async url => {
    const $img = document.createElement('img')
    $img.src = url
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $img.onload = () => resolve($img)
        $img.onerror = reject
        $img.src = url
    })
}
```

#### Step 3

Converting the `img` element to a `dataURL` using a `canvas` element:

```js
const $canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
$canvas.width = $svg.clientWidth
$canvas.height = $svg.clientHeight
$canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, $svg.clientWidth, $svg.clientHeight)
return $canvas.toDataURL(`image/${format}`, 1.0)
```

#### Step 4

Loading the converted `dataURL` into a new `img` element:

```js
const $img = document.createElement('img')
$img.src = dataURL
$holder.appendChild($img)
```

Here you have a working snippet:

```js
const dataHeader = 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'
const $svg = document.getElementById('svg-container').querySelector('svg')
const $holder = document.getElementById('img-container')
const $label = document.getElementById('img-format')

const destroyChildren = $element => {
  while ($element.firstChild) {
    const $lastChild = $element.lastChild ?? false
    if ($lastChild) $element.removeChild($lastChild)
  }
}

const loadImage = async url => {
  const $img = document.createElement('img')
  $img.src = url
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $img.onload = () => resolve($img)
    $img.onerror = reject
  })
}

const serializeAsXML = $e => (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString($e)

const encodeAsUTF8 = s => `${dataHeader},${encodeURIComponent(s)}`
const encodeAsB64 = s => `${dataHeader};base64,${btoa(s)}`

const convertSVGtoImg = async e => {
  const $btn = e.target
  const format = $btn.dataset.format ?? 'png'
  $label.textContent = format

  destroyChildren($holder)

  const svgData = encodeAsUTF8(serializeAsXML($svg))

  const img = await loadImage(svgData)
  
  const $canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
  $canvas.width = $svg.clientWidth
  $canvas.height = $svg.clientHeight
  $canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, $svg.clientWidth, $svg.clientHeight)
  
  const dataURL = await $canvas.toDataURL(`image/${format}`, 1.0)
  console.log(dataURL)
  
  const $img = document.createElement('img')
  $img.src = dataURL
  $holder.appendChild($img)
}

const buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-format]')]
for (const $btn of buttons) {
  $btn.onclick = convertSVGtoImg
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 100vw;
}

.images {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 70%;
}

.image {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.label {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item images">
    <div class="image left">
      <div class="label">svg</div>
      <div id="svg-container">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 248 204">
  <path fill="#1d9bf0" d="M221.95 51.29c.15 2.17.15 4.34.15 6.53 0 66.73-50.8 143.69-143.69 143.69v-.04c-27.44.04-54.31-7.82-77.41-22.64 3.99.48 8 .72 12.02.73 22.74.02 44.83-7.61 62.72-21.66-21.61-.41-40.56-14.5-47.18-35.07 7.57 1.46 15.37 1.16 22.8-.87-23.56-4.76-40.51-25.46-40.51-49.5v-.64c7.02 3.91 14.88 6.08 22.92 6.32C11.58 63.31 4.74 33.79 18.14 10.71c25.64 31.55 63.47 50.73 104.08 52.76-4.07-17.54 1.49-35.92 14.61-48.25 20.34-19.12 52.33-18.14 71.45 2.19 11.31-2.23 22.15-6.38 32.07-12.26-3.77 11.69-11.66 21.62-22.2 27.93 10.01-1.18 19.79-3.86 29-7.95-6.78 10.16-15.32 19.01-25.2 26.16z"/>
</svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image right">
      <div id="img-format" class="label"></div>
      <div id="img-container"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item buttons">
    <button id="btn-png" data-format="png">PNG</button>
    <button id="btn-jpg" data-format="jpeg">JPG</button>
    <button id="btn-webp" data-format="webp">WEBP</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in step 2 you are setting the `img.src` twice, I believe the second one is sufficient

Comment: the image in the `step 2` still contains a `data:image/svg+xml` image we use the canvas to convert it into another `format` (i.e. png, jpeg, ...) If in your case the `step 2` is enough great. I presented a complete solution for everybody.

Answer (score 11):

change `svg` to match your element

```
function svg2img(){
    var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
    var xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
    var svg64 = btoa(xml); //for utf8: btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(xml)))
    var b64start = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,';
    var image64 = b64start + svg64;
    return image64;
};svg2img()
```

Comment: it's not working for me, i get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'serializeToString' on 'XMLSerializer': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`

Comment: @Xsmael try to Switch the  DOMParser interface http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. No need to use external library.

Comment: @MahdiKhalili how?

Comment: @RyanArqueza what how?

Comment: when should I care about utf8?

Comment: @MTZ you should consider using utf8 part for utf8 characters for example your SVG contains non ASCI characters

Answer (score 11):

My use case was to have the svg data loaded from a network and this ES6 Class did the Job.

```
class SvgToPngConverter {
  constructor() {
    this._init = this._init.bind(this);
    this._cleanUp = this._cleanUp.bind(this);
    this.convertFromInput = this.convertFromInput.bind(this);
  }

  _init() {
    this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    this.imgPreview = document.createElement("img");
    this.imgPreview.style = "position: absolute; top: -9999px";

    document.body.appendChild(this.imgPreview);
    this.canvasCtx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
  }

  _cleanUp() {
    document.body.removeChild(this.imgPreview);
  }

  convertFromInput(input, callback) {
    this._init();
    let _this = this;
    this.imgPreview.onload = function() {
      const img = new Image();
      _this.canvas.width = _this.imgPreview.clientWidth;
      _this.canvas.height = _this.imgPreview.clientHeight;
      img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
      img.src = _this.imgPreview.src;
      img.onload = function() {
        _this.canvasCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        let imgData = _this.canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        if(typeof callback == "function"){
            callback(imgData)
        }
        _this._cleanUp();
      };
    };

    this.imgPreview.src = input;
  }
}
```

Here is how you use it

```
let input = "https://restcountries.eu/data/afg.svg"
new SvgToPngConverter().convertFromInput(input, function(imgData){
    // You now have your png data in base64 (imgData). 
    // Do what ever you wish with it here.
});
```

If you want a vanilla JavaScript version, you could [head over to Babel website](https://babeljs.io/repl) and transpile the code there.

Answer (score 10):

Here a function that **works without libraries** and returns a **Promise**:

```
/**
 * converts a base64 encoded data url SVG image to a PNG image
 * @param originalBase64 data url of svg image
 * @param width target width in pixel of PNG image
 * @return {Promise<String>} resolves to png data url of the image
 */
function base64SvgToBase64Png (originalBase64, width) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let img = document.createElement('img');
        img.onload = function () {
            document.body.appendChild(img);
            let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            let ratio = (img.clientWidth / img.clientHeight) || 1;
            document.body.removeChild(img);
            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = width / ratio;
            let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            try {
                let data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                resolve(data);
            } catch (e) {
                resolve(null);
            }
        };
        img.onerror = function() {
            resolve(null);
        };
        img.src = originalBase64;
    });
}
```

On Firefox there is an [issue for SVGs without set width / height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690643/firefox-error-rendering-an-svg-image-to-html5-canvas-with-drawimage).

See this [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/ymjqh9xg/) including a fix for the Firefox issue.

Comment: Didn't work for me in Safari, just hung, no error

Comment: Thanks for testing, I didn't test with Safari before. So there is also no error in the Javascript console, which would be strange?

Comment: Yes, very odd in my experience, but I didn't have more time to waste on it unfortunately

Comment: Thanks for including that fantastic example!

Comment: 1) I suggest attaching to img.onerror also to not risk stalling the Promise in that case.
2) you don't have to attach the image to the document.body.

Comment: @FredrikBlomqvist: (1) correct, I've added it. (2) Yes, I do have to attach it to body, in order to get the correct image ratio, see example with rectangular image and see the difference if you remove adding it to body: https://jsfiddle.net/3kba4gh9/ (tested in current FF)

Comment: @klues hmm, but why do you need to use img.clientWidth? If you use img.naturalWidth or img.width it works without attaching to DOM.

Answer (score 2):

`Svg` to `png` can be converted depending on conditions:

1. If `svg` is in format [SVG (string) paths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths):

- create canvas
- create `new Path2D()` and set `svg` as parameter
- draw path on canvas
- create image and use `canvas.toDataURL()` as `src`.

example:

```
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let svgText = 'M10 10 h 80 v 80 h -80 Z';
let p = new Path2D('M10 10 h 80 v 80 h -80 Z');
ctx.stroke(p);
let url = canvas.toDataURL();
const img = new Image();
img.src = url;
```

Note that `Path2D` not supported in `ie` and partially supported in edge. Polyfill solves that:
https://github.com/nilzona/path2d-polyfill

2. Create `svg` blob and draw on canvas using `.drawImage()`:

- make canvas element
- make a svgBlob object from the svg xml
- make a url object from domUrl.createObjectURL(svgBlob);
- create an Image object and assign url to image src
- draw image into canvas
- get png data string from canvas: canvas.toDataURL();

Nice description:
https://web.archive.org/web/20200125162931/http://ramblings.mcpher.com:80/Home/excelquirks/gassnips/svgtopng

Note that in ie you will get exception on stage of canvas.toDataURL(); It is because IE has too high security restriction and treats canvas as readonly after drawing image there. All other browsers restrict only if image is cross origin.

3. Use `canvg` JavaScript library. It is separate library but has useful functions.

Like:

```
ctx.drawSvg(rawSvg);
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Comment: 3rd link is broken

Comment: yes, indeed. I don't know how to reach there now. But description above can be enough for some understanding. Good idea for future co copy some context after the reference

Comment: fixed linkrot. the wayback machine is your friend for fixing linkrot.

Answer (score 2):

1. get [data URIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs) from SVG:

   > `data:image/svg+xml;base64,${btoa(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgElem))}`
2. prepare an [Image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image)
3. create a canvas and use [toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) to export.

#### Example

```html
<!-- test data-->
<svg width="400" height="400"><g transform="translate(23.915343915343925,-80.03971756398937)" class="glyph" stroke="#000000" fill="#a0a0a0"><path d="M74.97 108.70L74.97 108.70L100.08 110.77Q93.89 147.91 87.35 179.89L87.35 179.89L148.23 179.89L148.23 194.34Q143.76 277.91 113.84 339.81L113.84 339.81Q144.44 363.54 163.70 382.46L163.70 382.46L146.51 402.75Q128.62 384.18 101.80 361.83L101.80 361.83Q75.32 405.85 34.39 436.80L34.39 436.80L17.20 415.82Q57.43 386.93 82.20 345.66L82.20 345.66Q57.78 326.40 27.86 304.39L27.86 304.39Q44.37 257.96 56.75 203.97L56.75 203.97L19.26 203.97L19.26 179.89L61.90 179.89Q69.47 145.16 74.97 108.70ZM93.20 323.99L93.20 323.99Q118.65 272.06 123.12 203.97L123.12 203.97L82.20 203.97Q69.47 260.03 55.71 297.17L55.71 297.17Q76.01 311.61 93.20 323.99ZM160.26 285.13L160.26 260.37L239.71 260.37L239.71 216.01Q268.25 191.24 294.05 155.48L294.05 155.48L170.58 155.48L170.58 130.71L322.94 130.71L322.94 155.48Q297.49 191.93 265.50 223.92L265.50 223.92L265.50 260.37L337.38 260.37L337.38 285.13L265.50 285.13L265.50 397.59Q265.50 431.64 237.65 431.64L237.65 431.64L187.09 431.64L180.21 407.57Q202.22 407.91 227.67 407.91L227.67 407.91Q239.71 407.91 239.71 390.03L239.71 390.03L239.71 285.13L160.26 285.13Z"></path></g></svg>

<button title="download">svg2png</button>
<script>
    const output = {"name": "result.png", "width": 64, "height": 64}
    document.querySelector("button").onclick = () => {
        const svgElem = document.querySelector("svg")
        // const uriData = `data:image/svg+xml;base64,${btoa(svgElem.outerHTML)}` // it may fail.
        const uriData = `data:image/svg+xml;base64,${btoa(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgElem))}`
        const img = new Image()
        img.src = uriData
        img.onload = () => {
            const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            [canvas.width, canvas.height] = [output.width, output.height]
            const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, output.width, output.height)

            //  download
            const a = document.createElement("a")
            const quality = 1.0 // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/imageSmoothingQuality
            a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", quality)
            a.download = output.name
            a.append(canvas)
            a.click()
            a.remove()
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently discovered a couple of image tracing libraries for JavaScript that indeed are able to build an acceptable approximation to the bitmap, both size and quality. I'm developing this JavaScript library and CLI :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-png-converter

Which provides unified API for all of them, supporting browser and node, non depending on DOM, and a Command line tool.

For converting logos/cartoon/like images it does excellent job. For photos / realism some tweaking is needed since the output size can grow a lot.

It has a playground although right now I'm working on a better one, easier to use, since more features has been added:

https://cancerberosgx.github.io/demos/svg-png-converter/playground/#

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to convert SVG to PNG using the **Canvg** library.

In my case, I needed to get the **PNG blob from inline SVG**.

The library documentation provides an [example](https://canvg.github.io/canvg/index.html) (see OffscreenCanvas example).

But this method **does not work** at the moment in **Firefox**. Yes, you can enable the gfx.offscreencanvas.enabled option in the settings. But will every user on the site do this? :)

However, there is another way that will work in Firefox too.

```
const el = document.getElementById("some-svg"); //this is our inline SVG

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'); //create a canvas for the SVG render
canvas.width = el.clientWidth; //set canvas sizes
canvas.height = el.clientHeight;

const svg = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(el); //convert SVG to string

//render SVG inside canvas
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const v = await Canvg.fromString(ctx, svg);
await v.render();

let canvasBlob = await new Promise(resolve => canvas.toBlob(resolve));
```

For the last line thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57942679/13511039) answer

Answer (score 0):

Here are my 2 cents. Somehow `Download` anchor tag is not working as expected in code snippet, however it was working fine in `Chrome`.

Here is working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/80ba4gLx/)

```js
const waitForImage = imgElem => new Promise(resolve => imgElem.complete ? resolve() : imgElem.onload = imgElem.onerror = resolve);

const svgToImgDownload = ext => {
  if (!['png', 'jpg', 'webp'].includes(ext))
    return;
  const _svg = document.querySelector("#svg_container").querySelector('svg');
  const xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
  let _svgStr = xmlSerializer.serializeToString(_svg);
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + window.btoa(_svgStr);
  waitForImage(img)
    .then(_ => {
      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = _svg.clientWidth;
      canvas.height = _svg.clientHeight;
      canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, _svg.clientWidth, _svg.clientHeight);
      return canvas.toDataURL('image/' + (ext == 'jpg' ? 'jpeg' : ext), 1.0);
    })
    .then(dataURL => {
      console.log(dataURL);
      document.querySelector("#img_download_btn").innerHTML = `<a href="${dataURL}" download="img.${ext}">Download</a>`;
    })
    .catch(console.error);
};

document.querySelector('#map2Png').addEventListener('click', _ => svgToImgDownload('png'));
document.querySelector('#map2Jpg').addEventListener('click', _ => svgToImgDownload('jpg'));
document.querySelector('#map2Webp').addEventListener('click', _ => svgToImgDownload('webp'));
```

```html
<div id="svg_container" style="float: left; width: 50%">
  <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="-100 -100 200 200">
    <circle cx="0" cy="20" r="70" fill="#D1495B" />
    <circle cx="0" cy="-75" r="12" fill="none" stroke="#F79257" stroke-width="2" />
    <rect x="-17.5" y="-65" width="35" height="20" fill="#F79257" />
  </svg>
</div>

<div>
  <button id="map2Png">PNG</button>
  <button id="map2Jpg">JPG</button>
  <button id="map2Webp">WEBP</button>
</div>

<div id="img_download_btn"></div>
```

Comment: `if (!['jpg'].includes(ext)) return` and `ext == 'jpg' ? 'jpeg'` will never reach if someone uses jpeg, guessing you meant `['png','jpg','jpeg','webp']`

Answer (score -2):

If the goal is to convert an SVG file to a PNG image file via a browser, maybe the following website can help for those who need it quickly :

https://mybyways.com/blog/convert-svg-to-png-using-your-browser

[image]

Enter the SVG code in this section, then click the Load SVG button

[image]

A preview of the SVG image will appear and can be downloaded or saved as a PNG image file by pressing the Save SVG as PNG button.