# Convert Raphael SVG to image (png etc) client side

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert SVG to image (JPEG, PNG, etc.) in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/convert-svg-to-image-jpeg-png-etc-in-the-browser)

I have a small project where users construct a diagram using Raphael and then export the composed diagram to an image to save.

Problem is it has to run offline. http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/ will not work as it requires a canvas, not the Raphael generated SVG.

Is there a way (javascript) that I can export an image from the SVG?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, that duplicate question was a big help. canvg combined with canvas2image sorted me out.

So I created the SVG using Raphael. Then on a button click, saved the inner HTML of the div holding the SVG in a variable, then used that in canvg, hiding the SVG div. I could then use the ID of the canvas for canvas2image. It only really worked well for PNG.