# Raphael Export to PNG

Tags: svg, raphael, jquery-svg

I have the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/JQPurfect/mkz4s9j3/29/

```
     $("#editor_save").click(function() {
           var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('raphaelDiv'), 200, 200);

          // circle is for testing but I need svg_paper as the canvas object
           var circle = paper.circle(50, 40, 10);
           circle.attr("fill", "#f00");
           circle.attr("stroke", "#fff");
           var circle2 = paper.circle(70, 60, 50);

           //Use raphael.export to fetch the SVG from the paper
           var svg = paper.toSVG();

           //Use canvg to draw the SVG onto the empty canvas
           canvg(document.getElementById('myCanvas'), svg);

           setTimeout(function() {
               //fetch the dataURL from the canvas and set it as src on the image
               var dataURL = document.getElementById('myCanvas').toDataURL("image/png");
               document.getElementById('myImg').src = dataURL;
           }, 100);


    });
```

However I need to save the **svg_paper** to png but can't fig it out. The idea is to draw freehand on **svg_paper** and save that as an image once click "save" button.

Can you update the fiddle with it?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe you take a look at  [Convert Raphael SVG to image (png etc) client side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086703/convert-raphael-svg-to-image-png-etc-client-side)

Comment: I looked at it but doesn't work.

Comment: There are different answers. Which did you try and what did not work?