# Problem saving as png a SVG generated by Raphael JS in a canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, svg, raphael

I'm trying to convert a SVG generated by [Raphael JS](http://raphaeljs.com/) (and the user, since you can drag and rotate the images).
I followed this [Convert SVG to image (JPEG, PNG, etc.) in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/conversion-of-svg-to-jpeg/3976034#3976034) but still can't get it.

It must be easy but I can't put my finger on what I get wrong.

I got my svg in a div with `#ec` as `id` and the canvas's one is `#canvas`.

```
function saveDaPicture(){
    var img = document.getElementById('canvas').toDataURL("image/png");
    $('body').append('<img src="'+img+'"/>');
}
$('#save').click(function(){
    var svg = $('#ec').html();
    alert(svg);
    canvg('canvas', svg, {renderCallback: saveDaPicture(), ignoreMouse: true, ignoreAnimation: true});
});
```

The alert gives me :

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="600" height="512">
<desc>Created with Raphael</desc>
<defs></defs>
<image x="0" y="0" width="300" height="512" preserveAspectRatio="none" href="imageurl.jpg"></image>
<rect x="168" y="275" width="52" height="70" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-dasharray="8,3" transform="rotate(21.91207728 194 310)" style="opacity: 1; display: none; " opacity="1"></rect>
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#000"></circle>
<image x="358" y="10" width="39" height="138" preserveAspectRatio="none" href="imageurl2.png" style="cursor: move; "></image>
<image x="397" y="10" width="99" height="153" preserveAspectRatio="none" href="imageurl3.png" style="cursor: move; "></image>
<image x="184" y="286" width="10" height="10" preserveAspectRatio="none" href="imageurl4.png" style="cursor: pointer; opacity: 1; display: none; " opacity="1"></image>
<image x="204" y="286" width="10" height="10" preserveAspectRatio="none" href="imageurl5.png" style="cursor: pointer; opacity: 1; display: none; " opacity="1"></image>
<image x="170" y="277" width="48" height="66" preserveAspectRatio="none" href="imageurl6.png" style="cursor: move; opacity: 1; " r="50" opacity="1" transform="rotate(21.91207728 194 310)"></image>
</svg>
```

which is the xml of the svg and if I believe [canvg documentation](http://code.google.com/p/canvg/), it's good.

Anyway, with this code, the variable `img`, which should have the converted image data, got the data of an empty png with the dimensions of the svg.

The only thing I guess is that the svg generated by Raphael JS is not well formated for canvg (like, `href` of `image` should be `xlink:href` if I follow [the W3C recommandations](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#ImageElement) )

Anyone got an idea on this problem ? :D

Comment: Does the canvg canvas render the image correctly? Can you link to a live example that I could play around with?

Comment: @Shikiryu Did you find any solution? I have similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556447/merge-images-from-raphael-svg)

Answer (score 6):

`canvg` accepts the `SVG` data a file path or a single-line string

but in your code, your are passing the html content of the div `#ec` as

```
canvg('canvas', svg, {renderCallback: saveDaPicture, ignoreMouse: true, ignoreAnimation: true});
```

Both jQuery's `$.html()` and DOM's `innerHTML` methods return the HTML content of an element as is, so most probably in multiple lines.

`canvg` interprets this multi-line html content as a file path,

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="600" height="512">
```

and tries to fetch the data from the malformed url.

So the SVG to Canvas conversion process failed and that's the reason you are not getting the image as expect.

Here is a updated version that should work,

```
function saveDaPicture(){
    var img = document.getElementById('canvas').toDataURL("image/png");
    $('body').append('<img src="'+img+'"/>');
}

$('#save').click(function(){
    var svg = $('#ec').html().replace(/>\s+/g, ">").replace(/\s+</g, "<");
                             // strips off all spaces between tags
    //alert(svg);
    canvg('canvas', svg, {renderCallback: saveDaPicture, ignoreMouse: true, ignoreAnimation: true});
});
```

Comment: It may be this, now that you point it out. Isn't there a way in JS to make a multiline into only one line?

Comment: of course you can convert multiline to singleline, i'm updating my answer

Answer (score 2):

svgfix.js will solve this errors. 
take a look at this blog post [Export Raphael Graphic to Image](http://phpepe.com/2012/07/export-raphael-graphic-to-image.html)

Comment: Hi Ignacio!  Here on Stack Overflow, [link only answers are not considered answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259).  Unless you flesh it out with some code, your answer is in danger of being deleted per the [faq#deletion] section on deletion, especially "*Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are … barely more than a link to an external site*"

Comment: which is a shame, because this is the best answer

Comment: Just an FYI, this requires a `<canvas>` element which is not generated by Raphael and does not work in older browsers.  There are certainly workarounds but keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I worked with [SVG - Edit](http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/) and generated SVG images, what we did was install [ImageMagic](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) on the server (you probably have it installed already).

Once installed you only need to do execute a command like "convert foo.svg foo.png" in the terminal. If you are using php then you can do:

```
shell_exec("convert image.svg image.png");
```

In php and it's done.

Comment: Unfortunatly, I don't have ImageMagick installed on my server which is shared so I can't install it either. Nonetheless, it's quite a nice hint if someone got the same problem as mine. +1