# RaphaelJS to SVG to

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, png, raphael

I'm trying to let user download SVG graphic as PNG.
You may reach the code via [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cilerler/dZEQ4/)

SVG to CANVAS part is not working.

Already added canvg and Mozillas's code neither of them working.  Also added Canvas2Image which should works if canvas has element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to gabelerner who developed canvg helped me to fix it

1. based on [Problem saving as png a SVG generated by Raphael JS in a canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216927/problem-saving-as-png-a-svg-generated-by-raphael-js-in-a-canvas), strip off all spaces between tags in svg
2. based on [Problem saving as png a SVG generated by Raphael JS in a canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216927/problem-saving-as-png-a-svg-generated-by-raphael-js-in-a-canvas) image's href changed as xlink:href
3. based on gabelerner, added xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" into svg xlmns
4. based on gabelerner, image must be under the same domain - no crossside
5. based on gabelerner, Canvas2Image can't work within frame which means no FIDDLE (thus I deleted FIDDLE part to make it clear)

Here is the sample SVG and JS part you may want to have

```js
var svg_XML_NoSpace = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="1024" height="768"><desc>Created with Raphaël</desc><defs></defs><image x="0" y="0" width="1024" height="768" preserveaspectratio="none" xlink:href="http://<mydomain>/<myfolder>/<myfile>"></image><path fill="none" stroke="#ff0000" d="M414,114L722,114" style="stroke-width: 3px;" stroke-width="3"></path></svg>'; //based on gabelerner

//add canvas into body        
var canvasID = "myCanvas";
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.id = canvasID;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

//convert svg to canvas
canvg(document.getElementById(canvasID), svg_XML_NoSpace, { 
    ignoreMouse: true, ignoreAnimation: true, 
    renderCallback: function () {
         //save canvas as image
         Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(document.getElementById(canvasID));  
         }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting SVG to canvas with [fabric.js](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js) (here's a [demo](http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/test/demo/), in which svg is converted to canvas in real time, when you click on a button in sidebar).

Fabric doesn't support all SVG features but it should work for simple cases.

Here's an example of using `loadSVGFromURL`.

1) You'll need to have <canvas> element:

```
<canvas id="my-canvas"></canvas>
```

2) Initialize `fabric.Element` out of the canvas:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Element('my-canvas');
```

3) Fetch SVG via XHR:

```
canvas.loadSVGFromURL('path_to_your_shape.svg', function(objects, options) {

  // `objects` is now an array of fabric objects representing 
  // svg shapes from the document
  // if it's one shape, we'll just work with that
  // if it's more than one — we'll create a unified group out of it, 
  // using `fabric.PathGroup`

  var loadedObject = objects.length > 1 
    ? new fabric.PathGroup(objects, options) 
    : objects[0];

  // we can now change object's properties like left, top, angle, opacity, etc.
  // this is not necessary, of course

  loadedObject.set({
    left: 123,
    top: 321,
    angle: 55,
    opacity: 0.3
  });

  // and add it to canvas

  canvas.add(loadedObject);
});
```

Comment: thx for prompt reply, I couldn't find any function that takes SVG and converts it to Canvas in documents or demo.  If it wants me to parse SVG first than not the right solution for me.  Did I miss something?  Please advise.  thx...

Comment: Updated with an example. Is this clearer? Would that work for you? What `fabric` does is it creates its own representation of SVG shapes and renders them on canvas. It allows you to work with those objects programmatically (e.g. change their properties, add, remove, clone) and also manipulate them via UI (e.g. dragging shapes with mouse, rotating, scaling, etc.)

Comment: I tried fabric but I realized that it adds too much payload as file, I passed it.  Again, thank you very much for your time and attention.