# toDataURL throws dom exception 18 only from button click

Tags: javascript, html, dom, knockout.js, html5-canvas

im building a mobile web/native app using knockout and phonegap. i have this js code:

```
    self.endCanvas=function(id){
    var canvas;
    var data;
    switch(id){ 
    case 1: 
            canvas=$("#canvas1")[0];
            data=canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            console.log(data);
    }
};
```

and this html

```
    <canvas id="canvas1" width=300 height=250  data-bind="context: triggerRedraw, contextCallback:redrawCanvas"></canvas>
    <a  class="whiteButton" data-bind="click: endCanvas.bind($data,1)">המשך</a>
```

apperantly, the toDataURL() function works fine when written outside the self.endCanvas function, but throws security error when called from button click with the above code. anyone knows why?

Comment: Are you drawing something onto the canvas that is not hosted on the same domain? Cross-origin rules can cause a security error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [canvas.toDataURL() throws security exception, despite image being local](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187306/canvas-todataurl-throws-security-exception-despite-image-being-local)