# CanvasRenderingContext2D drawImage() not correctly working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

I am currently working on a web-application. As part of it I am creating SVG-images internally. When it comes to rendering, I used the approach provided in this question in order to convert the svg to a bitmap and displaying it on a canvas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23667012/5767042

Most of the times this works fine, however sometimes it does not render the SVG image. Using the chrome DevTools, I was able to confirm that the object being passed to `drawImage()` (in the example below this would be `imageBitmap`) is the same in **every call**, however sometimes it gets rendered and sometimes it does not. I don't understand this behaviour at all.

```js
var svgStr = "<svg xmlns=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2000\/svg\" width=\"100\" height=\"100\" shape-rendering=\"crispEdges\" stroke-linecap=\"square\"><line x1=\"0\" y1=\"0\" x2=\"50\" y2=\"50\" stroke=\"rgb(0,0,0)\" stroke-width=\"4\"\/><line x1=\"0\" y1=\"50\" x2=\"50\" y2=\"0\" stroke=\"rgb(0,0,0)\" stroke-width=\"4\"\/><\/svg>";

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var imageBitmap = new Image();
imageBitmap.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+window.btoa(svgStr);
console.log('drawing bitmap');

ctx.drawImage(imageBitmap, 0, 0);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
```

Am I using `drawImage()` in a wrong way? I had the same behaviour in Firefox, Edge doesn't work at all. I also tested it on three different machines, no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait until the image is finished loading. For that you can use the `.onload` handler of the image, which is called when it's loaded.

```js
var svgStr = "<svg xmlns=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2000\/svg\" width=\"100\" height=\"100\" shape-rendering=\"crispEdges\" stroke-linecap=\"square\"><line x1=\"0\" y1=\"0\" x2=\"50\" y2=\"50\" stroke=\"rgb(0,0,0)\" stroke-width=\"4\"\/><line x1=\"0\" y1=\"50\" x2=\"50\" y2=\"0\" stroke=\"rgb(0,0,0)\" stroke-width=\"4\"\/><\/svg>";

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var imageBitmap = new Image();
imageBitmap.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + window.btoa(svgStr);

function drawBitmap() {
  console.log('drawing bitmap');

  ctx.drawImage(imageBitmap, 0, 0);
}

imageBitmap.onload = drawBitmap;
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: That was it. I ruled this out because I created the SVG and bitmap programatically and everything is executed sequentially. Also the DevTools showed the correct information about the bitmap object. Do you know why it still happens?

Comment: The parser probably still takes time to create an internal copy of the image in the format it will be rendered