# Transform svg to png with image tag inside to get Base64 on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I'm having trouble of generating my SVG to PNG using `<image>` in order of getting Base64, my [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/meertskm/) shows that is not possible. Is there any workaround for this?

Or is it possible to transform this `data = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa(xml)` into `image/png;base64`? Based on this [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8srnfdk3/)

Comment: You don't seem to be using the SVG from the page in your javascript (I don't see `testimg1` anywhere).

Comment: its `id="asd"` on the svg

Comment: Oh, I guess I'm blind :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433806/convert-embedded-svg-to-png-in-place

Answer (score 0):

The `xlink:href` attribute appear to be cross-origin , which would result in error

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement':
Tainted canvases may not be exported.
```

being returned when `canvas.toDataURL()` called http://jsfiddle.net/meertskm/5/

---

Updated

Try utilizing `XMLHttpRequest` see [Sending and Receiving Binary Data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data)

> Also you can read a binary file as a Blob by setting the string "blob"
>   to the responseType property.

```js
    // create `img` element
    var img = new Image;
    img.width = 100;
    img.height = 100;
    // log when complete
    img.onload = function () {
        // see `src` at `this`
        console.log(this.complete, this);
    };
    // set `url` of `request` with `svg` `image` `xlink:href`
    var link = document.querySelectorAll("svg")[0]
              .children[0].attributes
              .getNamedItem("xlink:href").value;
    
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.responseType = "blob";
    request.open("GET", link, true);
            
    request.onload = function (e) {
        var blob = this.response;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            // `data URI` of request image
            console.log(e.target.result); 
            // set `img` `src` to `e.target.result`:`data URI`
            img.src = e.target.result;
            // append `img` next to `svg`
            document.body.appendChild(img);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    };
    // log error
    request.onerror = function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    };
    
    request.send();
```

```html
<svg height="100" width="100" id="asd" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <image id="testimg1" xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/LQIsf.jpg" width="100" height="100" x="0" y="0" />
</svg>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/meertskm/4/

Comment: Im unable to get Base64 on it. Give me empty image

Comment: @fsi See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424279/canvas-todataurl-securityerror , http://simonsarris.com/blog/480-understanding-the-html5-canvas-image-security-rules

Comment: So basically I cant see the image(base64) because of this error?

Comment: @fsi See updated post; utilized `XMLHttpRequest` to request image as `Blob` , `FileReader()` to convert `blob` response to `data URI`.