# Telerik asp.net Chart (svg) to png

Tags: asp.net, svg, png, telerik-mvc

I currently have a Telerik Chart component on my asp.net MVC page. The charts are displayed on the screen as SVG. I would like to output these SVGs as png. By output, I mean "download" these SVG to my machine as PNG.

Comment: Actually, I've found that my question is a "king of" a duplicate to this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/convert-svg-to-image-jpeg-png-etc-in-the-browser/3976034#3976034 It answered part of the question.

Comment: You can also use the solution from their code library. http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-mvc/general/chart-mvc-export.aspx