# Send user-made SVG (raphael.js) to server (php) so it can be sent by email

Tags: php, javascript, image, raphael

I have a page where users can create their own SVG images. Now I would like to access these images on the server (php) so they can be sent to an email address.

With these [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/convert-svg-to-image-jpeg-png-etc-in-the-browser/3976034#3976034) I am able to convert the SVG to a canvas and then convert the canvas to jpeg/png. I'm not worried about the SVG tree anymore as it doesn't need to be edited anymore, thus converting it to a normal image (I was assuming that would be easier to handle, ultimately I want to send that image as an attachment in the email).

What would be the most efficient way of doing this? Is it possible to POST the converted jpeg/png to the server? Thanks guys, kinda lost here.

Comment: What about posting the svg to the server and doing the conversion there?

Comment: I've thought about that too, but I still wouldn't know how to send the SVG to the server? :) Wouldn't I need to serialize it in some way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot more reading I managed to find a fairly simple solution, in case anyone has a similar problem here it is:

Once you have converted the SVG to a normal canvas using [canvg](http://code.google.com/p/canvg/) you can make use of the canvas.toDataURL() method, all you need to do then is POST the generated URL and decode it on the server. I used a hidden input field for this. Be careful not to use JQuery for getting the canvas, since JQuery doesn't return the actual canvas but a JQuery Object.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
$('#hiddenInput').val(dataUrl);
```

And on the server side:

```
$encodeData = $_POST['dataUrl'];
$encodeData = substr($encodeData, strpos($encodeData, ',') + 1); //strip the URL of its headers
$decodeData = base64_decode($encodeData);
$handle = fopen('test.png', 'x+');
fwrite($handle, $decodeData);
fclose($handle);
```

The SVG is now on the server as a png.