# Mysterious growth after copying a SVG to a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, svg, html5-canvas, canvg

I have a svg on my page that I need to export to a png, so following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/convert-svg-to-image-jpeg-png-etc-in-the-browser), I'm using canvg.

The copy seems to work fine at first but then the canvases height starts mysteriously increasing.

Am I doing something obviously wrong? I've tried setting all kinds of sizes for the canvas with no luck. Fails in IE and Chrome.

Here is my export function:

```
function copytocanvas()
{
    var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
    c.width = $('#svgChart').width();
    c.height = c.width;
    c.getContext = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext;


    var svg = document.getElementById('svgChart'); // or whatever you call it
    var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
    var str = serializer.serializeToString(svg);

    canvg(c, str);  
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle to show the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/4772/

The problem seems to get worse when scrolling!

Comment: It looks like canvg is, for some reason, resizing the canvas whenever the mouse is moved. `canvg(c, str, {ignoreMouse:true});` stops the canvas from resizing constantly, but the canvas is still over-sized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`canvg(c, str, {ignoreMouse:true, ignoreDimensions:true});`

edit:

It looks like you don't need to `ignoreMouse`:

`canvg(c, str, {ignoreDimensions:true});` should do the trick.