# Styling errors when converting inline SVG to png

Tags: javascript, css, svg, canvg

My high level goal is to convert a `<div>` element containing a few inline svg images to a png file. All operations must be performed within the client browser using JavaScript. I have tried:

1. using canvg library and following the steps from this post: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/95#issuecomment-34439223

   original svg:

   [image: original svg]

   result:

   [image: canvg result]
2. flattening the css styles into the `<svg>` tag and then calling canvg, following the steps from this post: [Convert embedded SVG to PNG in-place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433806/convert-embedded-svg-to-png-in-place/21318963#21318963)

   result: a blank image.
3. flattening the css styles into the `<svg>` tag and manually drawing the svg onto a canvas, following the steps from this post:
   [how to save/ export inline SVG styled with css from browser to image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181452/how-to-save-export-inline-svg-styled-with-css-from-browser-to-image-file/18006981#18006981)

   result: a blank image.
4. flattening the css styles into an inline style sheet using this code: http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/01/21/convert-svg-to-png/

   result: a blank image.
5. using [svg crowbar](http://nytimes.github.io/svg-crowbar/) to manually download the `<div>` element as an .svg file.

   result:

   [image]

   then when I compared the computed css of the original svg against the downloaded svg, I found that the downloaded svg had the correct svg xml but an incorrect inline stylesheet (`<style type="text/css">`) For example the numbers 200, 300 on the far right of the graph, they were drawn with `<text x="214" dy=".32em" y="0" style="text-anchor: start;">200</text>` and in my external css, I have:

   .scatterChart .axisGraphicsContext text {
       font-size: 8px;
       fill: #777;
   }

   However, the font-size and fill properties were absent from the inline stylesheet of the downloaded svg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been searching myself for a solution to export PNG with CSS created through Rickshaw (based on D3). The sole solution I found was to:

- treat the DIVs different from the SVGs, and treat them all individually
- convert the DIVs (and other non-SVG content) with html2canvas to canvas
- make the CSS inline to the SVG; @thirdcreed has posted the JavaScript code and D3 selectors for that at: [Rickshaw CSS/Axes in JSDOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996847/rickshaw-css-axes-in-jsdom) - adapt that to your custom CSS as needed.
- convert the SVGs into canvas with code such as

  ```
  var imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+ btoa(html2);
  var img = '<img src="'+imgsrc+'">';      
  var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");      
  var image = new Image;
  image.src = imgsrc;
  image.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  }
  ```
- merge the different canvases you have into one
- convert into image with code such as:

  ```
  var canvasdata = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  var pngimg = '<img src="'+canvasdata+'">'; 
  d3.select("#pngdataurl").html(pngimg); // contains selector from D3, adjust if you don't use D3
  var a = document.getElementById("some_anchor"); // Fix for Firefox: supply an anchor-tag here that is 'display:none' in your document, otherwise download won't work
  a.download = "sample.png";
  a.href = canvasdata;
  a.click();
  ```

Note that every browser expect for Internet Explorer requires the SVGs to have the xmlns attribute.