# html2canvas generated image not picking svg in chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, html2canvas

I have used svg icons in my app & used svg to draw charts too.When I generate image using html2canvas all the svgs are ignored & image is generated without all svgs.

I am using below function to generate image.

```
function svgToCanvas (targetElem) {
        var nodesToRecover = [];
        var nodesToRemove = [];

        var svgElem = targetElem.find('svg');

        svgElem.each(function(index, node) {
            var parentNode = node.parentNode;
            var svg = parentNode.innerHTML;

            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

            canvg(canvas, svg);

            nodesToRecover.push({
                parent: parentNode,
                child: node
            });
            parentNode.removeChild(node);

            nodesToRemove.push({
                parent: parentNode,
                child: canvas
            });

            parentNode.appendChild(canvas);
        });

        html2canvas(targetElem, {
            allowTaint: true,
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                // var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                // ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
                // ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
                // ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

                var img_PNG = Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
            }
        });
    }
```

This function is called like this `svgToCanvas($("#app-container"));`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I forgot to answer this question.Someone up vote my question so came into mind.

Actually **html2canvas** is converting to image but it was not picking style of the SVG as it was writtedn in different css file.So if you want to get styles of **SVG** in image you have to **give style inline within tags**.Then you will get complete and colorful image.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript passes objects by reference (see [Does Javascript pass by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference) or [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language) for explanations) which means that the SVGs are edited out by `parentNode.removeChild(node);` insides the `svgElem.each` loop before html2canvas gets to work on them.

However, changing that might not help - telling from my experience html2canvas doesn't render SVG. That can be done manually - here's an answer with source code which might help you achieve that manually: [Styling errors when converting inline SVG to png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939491/styling-errors-when-converting-inline-svg-to-png/28025034#28025034)