# Save svg(in div) to png or convert to png. Raphaël JS

Tags: html, svg, png, raphael

I'm new to Raphaël and javascript and got a question of how to save the svg (in div) to png using Javascript. I read may articles: such as using canvg https://code.google.com/p/canvg/  and `canvas.toDataURL('image/png');` ..etc but still don't know how to do it.

I'm trying to convert the qrcodesvg.js output (http://vp-dev.net/qrcodesvg/) to some downloadable/readable png/image formats in the client side. May someone give me some hints which or what basic reference(s) to look at? Thanks!

Kind regards,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert SVG to image (JPEG, PNG, etc.) in the browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/convert-svg-to-image-jpeg-png-etc-in-the-browser)

Comment: Thank you, Robert. But I read that article before I post this one (can't post more than 2 links). OK, and I find out the hidden Html SVG tag using Opera Dragonfly: `<div id="qrcode">
<svg height="250" version="1.1" width="250" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="overflow:hidden;position:relative">` I notice that the SVG is nested under qrcode div and it's the main problem I can't fetch SVG with id qrcode!

Comment: OK, here's the update: Simply use the getElementsByTagName `document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].id = 'id_something';` and set the svg tag with id something, then using `canvg(canvas, svg);` and `var img_url = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');` you will get the png file you wanted.

Am I doing the right way? Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Some days ago i had your same problem. In reality, i needed to convert an svg containing images: in this case we have to export manually each image in Base64. However the snippet below should work also in your case. I used [Raphael.Export](https://github.com/ElbertF/Raphael.Export) library in order to obtain the SVG.

```
var svgData = r.paper.toSVG(), //Obtaining the SVG element
              parser = new DOMParser(),
              //converting the svg in a DOM object
              doc = parser.parseFromString(svgData, "text/xml");

//Getting all the images element in the SVG
var images = doc.querySelectorAll( "image" );
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

var ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );

var i, imgArr = new Array();
for(i=0; i<images.length; i++){
    //for each image element, i need to obtain its Base64 representation
    imgArr[i] = document.createElement("img");
    imgArr[i].setAttribute( "src", images[i].href.baseVal);

    imgArr[i].onload = function(i, images){
        return function() {
            ctx.drawImage( imgArr[i], 0, 0 );
            // Replace the image href with its base64 representation
            svgData = svgData.replace(images[i].href.baseVal,canvas.toDataURL( "image/png" ));
            //if i'm converting the last element, create the img result
            if(i==images.length-1){
                 var img = document.createElement('img'), canv = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
                     //generating the result svg image
                     img.setAttribute( "src", "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa(svgData));
                     var context= canv.getContext( "2d" );

                     //when the img ready, we can obtain the png 
                     img.onload = function() {
                            context.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );
                            var canvasdata = canv.toDataURL("image/png");
                            var pngimg =  document.getElementById( "myImg" ); 
                            pngimg.setAttribute( "src", canvasdata);
                            //now pngimg contains the resulting image
                     };
            }
        }   
    }(i, images);
}
```

And inside your html document, you need an img tag with id="myImg"

I hope it could help :)