# How to convert an edited SVG object to save as an image (Png\Jpg) in a pdf document

Tags: c#, javascript, html, svg

I am using an  or  tag to load an SVG file into my html. This file is then edited in javascript by the user(customize, Hide/show elements and color).

The last step of the customization is that i need to save all data in a pdf document, and the SVG is where i am having trouble. I do an ajax request to an asmx service (with all parameters) to create the pdf.

My current approach to the svg problem is to try to get the XML content and draw it in a canvas then save it to an image in order for me to pass it as a parameter to the web service but no luck. I also tried to get the svg content and trasform it to a dataURL to create the image object:

```
var svg = document.getElementById("testObj").getSVGDocument();
var svgText = svg.documentElement;
var mySrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + window.btoa(svgText);
var source = new Image();
source.src = mySrc;
```

Where testObj is the embed or object tag containing the svg.
I am obviously doing something wrong in both cases.

I want to know what is the best way to handle this scenario. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert SVG to image (JPEG, PNG, etc.) in the browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/convert-svg-to-image-jpeg-png-etc-in-the-browser)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. This is not what i am looking for though. I do not want to load it from a path to a canvas. I need to manipulate it first as an object and then extract it with its changes into a pdf or at least into a jpg/png image.