# SVG to PNG in javascript with filter support

Tags: javascript, svg, filter, png, canvg

I've been using this method to convert SVGs to PNGs using canvg:

[Convert SVG to image (JPEG, PNG, etc.) in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/convert-svg-to-image-jpeg-png-etc-in-the-browser).

However, canvg does not have support for feColorMatrix filters, which I need for my project. Does anyone know of an alternative conversion method, or a fix for this issue? Thanks!