# How does Facebook fun apps create images from information fetched?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, html2canvas

This thing is really irritating. Actually I know how to convert HTML to image using [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) library. But I just want to know how most of the people who have Facebook fun apps like [this](http://in.369rocks.com/signfollow) and [this](http://en.mallu-apps.com/activities/question/most-ranked-profile-pictures-en/97?utm_source=MiddleBar&utm_medium=result&utm_campaign=Activity), create images.

I can get all the required user information using **FB API**, then how should I create an JPG/PNG image like them? What I have tried is `html2canvas` but I don't think all other fun apps use this thing. Because when viewed their source code, I couldn't see the HTML element containing all the content of the image that needs to be generated using `html2canvas`. Even the **canvas** element is **NOT** present. Only the image is displayed.

So, there can be **3** possibilities:

1. They do whole processing in a separate HTML/PHP page using Ajax (Which is another question, I searched a lot but couldn't find single answer related to that: See Query below).
2. They do hide the **HTML** and its corresponding **CANVAS** element using z-index or something and show only generated image.
3. They don't use `html2canvas`. They use something else.

**Query** related to **1**: Is it possible for Ajax call to execute an HTML page including JS, CSS (say `URL: 'convertAndReturnImage.php'` and render the result and return the generated **image/URL** using `html2canvas` in `success` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily combine images on the server - send all images to the server and place them with specific x/y coordinates. For example, PHP offers a lot of functions for this: http://php.net/manual/de/ref.image.php

You can also just combine the picture with canvas (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage), use the "toDataURL" function and send it to the server, of course. But you have to create it on the server. For example: [Decoding a canvas todataURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291183/decoding-a-canvas-todataurl)

You can either return the picture with AJAX or create it on the server and return the URL to it.

Comment: What do you mean by combine? I think you didn't get what I asked.

Comment: you can also combine images on the server instead of the client. you want to create images like in those screenshots, right?

Comment: there is really not much to it. you don´t need canvas, you just need the separate images and their x/y coordinates to place/combine them. that happens on the server. OR you use canvas and export the whole image to php.

Comment: i have added more information, check it out. also check out the php reference with the image functions.

Comment: Yes. I have created the canvas and I know how to export it as PNG and save it to server using `toDATAURL`. But thing is I don't want the canvas and its source (the DIV element and its content which has to be converted to canvas and to image) on the main page. I want to do it in some way that user won't see it.

Comment: then why not create a canvas element in the backround, with display:none? either do that, or combine pictures on the server with php functions.

Comment: Ok. But now I'm stuck at another problem. Could you please answer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22960471/html2canvas-js-not-capturing-image-for-dynamically-generated-content

Comment: so you still want to try with html2canvas? i would not use it, it´s buggy afaik and the pics are small, right? just use a hidden canvas and redraw it, or combine pictures with php.

Comment: How would I combine text on pictures?

Comment: just check out all the php functions for graphics, there are also functions for putting text on pictures (with pixel coordinates).

Comment: Ok I'll try PHP graphics. What do you mean by redraw the canvas? Using html2canvas?

Comment: i just meant that you can use a hidden canvas, draw all elements on it and then use toDataURL, as i mentioned in my answer. that would be a lot easier.

Comment: Okay. But how would I draw image (that I want to place in it) in canvas?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Comment: Thank you :) It seems good approach. Also, I found this: https://github.com/Intervention/image I think it should solve my problem. I'm trying it.

Comment: I tried Intervention. Would you please check this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42779255/intervention-imagick-works-in-terminal-but-not-in-browser

Answer (score 1):

Ajax call can execute a script page only, like .js or .php. It can't execute a .php page containing HTML document, JS and stylesheet. For that, it has to be rendered in a browser. Ajax returns only result. This much processing can't be done any way. You have to open the document in a browser at least once.