# Intervention imagick works in terminal but not in browser

Tags: php, gd, imagick, intervention

I quite don't understand what's going wrong. I've installed Intervention from as guided [here](http://image.intervention.io/)

Then I created the following .php file and started my localhost Apache server and tested the results and it worked!

Here's the code:

**test.php**

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;
Image::configure(array('driver' => 'gd'));
$image = Image::make('ar.jpg');
$path = 'public/images/photoh.png';
$image->save($path);
?>
```

But when I run the same file using `php test.php` in Ubuntu terminal, I get the following error:

**GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation.**

When I checked the phpinfo(), I saw gd being listed there with version 2.1.0

This is not the real issue, but still I would like to know what can be wrong and how can I solve it.

Then comes the real problem. I installed **Imagick** separately using following command:

`sudo apt-get install php-imagick`

This installed **Imagick 6.8** on my system (I checked this using convert -version)

Then I added following to php.ini file:

`extension=imagick.so`

And then for testing, I changed the driver to **'imagick'** in **test.php** and executed it using php in terminal and it worked fine.

But I want it to work on browser, like **GD**, but **IT DIDN'T**.

It showed the similar error that **GD** showed on terminal:

**ImageMagick module not available with this PHP installation.**

So it seems like **ImageMagick** is installed but something is missing. Is there something I can do?

Ubuntu: 16.04 LTS
PHP: 5.6

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there are likely various php.ini files on your system.  You can find the various files by typing `locate php.ini` in a terminal.  Verify you're editing the intended version for the web.  Secondly, I would restart your web service.  If you're using apache you can type `sudo service apache2 restart` in a terminal to restart it.

Comment: I've edited the right .ini file. Also I have restarted server many times.