# phpinfo doesn't show imagick extension

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I'm trying since one week but it's not working. I've installed imagemagick on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I executed following command in terminal and got this:

`convert -version`

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2017-03-02 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC Modules OpenMP
Delegates: bzlib cairo djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png rsvg tiff wmf x xml zlib
```

That means it is installed? But in `phpinfo()` it doesn't show the imagick module. I added the extension in right php.ini file but still same result. Is this the issue with Ubuntu?

Further, I tried commands listed [here](https://tecadmin.net/install-imagemagick-on-linux/) but none of them worked. I got following error:

**E: Package 'php5' has no installation candidate**

**E: Package 'php5-common' has no installation candidate**

PS: I want this to work because I'm using [Intervention](https://github.com/Intervention) library for image editing and that is not working since **imagick** is not listed in phpinfo().

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/769396/how-to-install-imagemagick-for-php7-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: downvoter any valid reason for downvote?

Comment: @ewcz yes I have already installed using that but still `phpinfo()` doesn't show the imagick module

Comment: @ewcz you may want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42779255/intervention-imagick-works-in-terminal-but-not-in-browser/42779915#42779915

Answer (score 3):

you are using ubuntu 16.04 which is often use php7.0.8 .

in the same time that you are trying to install `imagick` for a different version of php

to install `imagick` follow this steps:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-common

sudo apt-get install php-imagick
```

after that make sure that you have enabled the extension and restarted your apache :

```
sudo phpenmod imagick

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I just executed above commands and still there's no extension listed in `phpinfo()`

Comment: what's your php version ? and what's that command's  output `php -m | grep imagick`

Comment: with php -m it shows only "imagick". with php -i it shows this => imagick
imagick module => enabled
imagick module version => 3.4.3
imagick classes => Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator, ImagickKernel
imagick.locale_fix => 0 => 0
imagick.progress_monitor => 0 => 0
imagick.skip_version_check => 0 => 0

Comment: Here's the elaboration of my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42779255/intervention-imagick-works-in-terminal-but-not-in-browser/42779915#42779915

Comment: `sudo phpenmod imagick;sudo service apache2 restart` this sould be enough , from my local machine `imagick module enabled` after following the previous steps

Comment: Which OS? The imagick module is not listed and I'm still getting same error: 'ImageMagick module not available with this PHP installation.

Comment: Is there any specific place where I should add this in php.ini? I just put it randomly.

Comment: you don't need to add this `extension=imagick.so` manually at all! sudo phpenmod imagick enough , try to remove this lines from php.ini's and enable imagick again from the phpenmod command and check

Comment: Okay. I'm checking

Comment: It's still there :/