# Saving a SVG element as PNG on local system

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I am using D3 to produce an svg element with a graph on it.

What I am trying to achieve is to save my SVG element to a PNG file locally through the browser.

I am wanting it to save the svg as a png locally when the user clicks the save button

I have tried to use:

https://github.com/exupero/saveSvgAsPng

But get the error:

```
Error: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '[ng:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak, .ng-hide' is not a valid selector.
```

I have read other SO questions regarding the issue, but they don't make full sense to me.

Any help would be good.

Comment: Depending on browser support this post may have your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/convert-svg-to-image-jpeg-png-etc-in-the-browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with online services as well. Blitline.com for example lets you do it in a browser like via a custom URL, like this:

http://api.blitline.com/actions/vector_to_image?application_id=YOUR_APP_ID&src=https://s3.amazonaws.com/img.blitline/ai/butterfly.ai

Just replace "YOUR_APP_ID" with your free Blitline Application ID, and your browser will output a png version of the src vector.

There are also other options(like setting width, height, extension, etc) for the URL which you can find here:

http://www.blitline.com/docs/aliases

There are other services that do this as well. Blitline is just the one I am familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the context of your question, but this is a way of downloading an SVG and saving it as a PNG using ImageMagick - [here](http://www.imagemagick.org).

Say you have an SVG on the web [like here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/10/Type_B_Plug_BW.svg).

You can download it to your local machine with `curl` like this:

```
curl http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/10/Type_B_Plug_BW.svg > x.svg
```

Then you can use ImageMagick to convert it to PNG like this:

```
convert x.svg x.png
```

Or you can do it all in one:

```
curl http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/10/Type_B_Plug_BW.svg | convert SVG:- x.png
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I have made a graph in D3, and when the user clicks on the save button i would like it to save it to local system.