# It is possible to save charts as images using am charts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

actually my requirement is to save the charts as images and saved it in server while loading the page.. I'm using amcharts so is there any possible way to do this.. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since amcharts appears to use SVG to display the graph, you could try the technique in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3976034/507784) (use a library called [canvg](http://code.google.com/p/canvg/) to save to a canvas, then send the image data from the canvas to the server).