# How can convert svg(data:image/svg+xml) to .png or .jpg

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts, bar-chart

When onclick Save as Image button,
I want to save or download Chart to .png or .jpg

[image: chart]

```
$scope.saveAsBinary = function () {
     var svg = document.getElementById('highchartContainer').children[0].innerHTML;
     var base_image = new Image();
     svg = "data:image/svg+xml," + svg;
     base_image.src = svg;
     $('#binaryImage').attr('src', svg);
}
```

Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwangkung1/2Nksq/1/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert SVG to image (JPEG, PNG, etc.) in the browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/convert-svg-to-image-jpeg-png-etc-in-the-browser)