# Convert SVG to JPEG to embedd in HTML

Tags: javascript, svg, outlook, jpeg

I'm using jSignature to capture a signature. I can capture and redisplay the signature without a problem, but I need to put the signature as part of the message body in a html mail.

The signature appears in a web based email browser like yahoo, but will not show up if the the mail is opened in Outlook. All other images in outlook appear OK.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert SVG to image (JPEG, PNG, etc.) in the browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/convert-svg-to-image-jpeg-png-etc-in-the-browser)

Answer (score 0):

Outlook uses Word, not IE to render HTML message. Word does not support `<img>` tags with embedded image data.