# Is there any way to export d3 output to visio file?

Tags: svg, d3.js, visio

Is there any way to export d3 output to a Visio file?

Comment: i think you can't. you can export to an image as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/convert-svg-to-image-jpeg-png-etc-in-the-browser

Answer (score 0):

Output of d3.js is normally an SVG file. 
You can open SVG files in Visio using File -> Open

Comment: You can open SVG and then save it as VDX using Visio 2003-2010. Note that VDX format is deprecated now and not supported for saving in Visio 2013.