# saving user generated image using HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, image, saving-data, user-generated-content

I want to save and an image that is user generated, and I can't use anything other than HTML an JavaScript. Is there a way to do it?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If it's SVG, this might touch on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/convert-svg-to-image-jpeg-png-etc-in-the-browser