# How to convert .xml into .jpg or .png using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, svg, jpeg

For my work I sketch building dimensions,and the software creates a .jpg file of the 2D sketch [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJKsL.png)

The problem is that sometimes if I haven't zoomed in on the software close enough, the resulting .jpg will leave the sketch blurry due to the large overall .jpg size (lots of white space).

The software also produces a .xml file which contains the dimensions, labels and coordinate points of the sketched building(s). I'm fairly new to XML but am wondering how do I use the data within the XML in order to generate a new image file (jpg/png) that will remove the white space and essentially make the resuting image only big enough to display the actual sketch, [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jPoE.png)

A snippet of the XML is shown below, and the full XML can be found just above it.

Thank you for your help.

```
http://codeshare.io/VUYsS


<SketchDocument DataVersion="1.28">
    <Sketch1 Guid="fcc6d177-d3a4-4a01-af7f-2721bc0327ca" SketchMouseLocation="336.0,-7.0">
        <Areas>
            <Area1 Guid="4faa25cf-5aeb-47f4-97e4-b334c7ca4a8d" GLALevel="1" Category="Common Areas" ShowDimensionLabels="True" ShowCalulation="True" ShowName="True" Continuous="True" LivingArea="True" NegativeArea="False" NonCalculated="False" TackedTo="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" IsNestedArea="False" IsExteriorNestedArea="False">
                <DimensionLabel Guid="4bbe3d57-aa5c-454f-80a8-17996e86fbb6" X="8.444992" Y="-91.37911" XOffset="-0.0" YOffset="-4.5499997" Visible="True" Rotation="0.0" RotationOverride="False" ParentRotation="0" Alignment="Center">
                    <Font ColorChanged="False" Color="ARGB(255,0,0,0)" Bold="False" Size="8" Underline="False" Family="Verdana" Italic="False" FontChanged="False"/>
                    <TextLines>814.8 Sq '</TextLines>
                </DimensionLabel>
                <NameLabel Guid="b3837229-f021-4a7b-9c89-2148ba9c6315" X="8.444992" Y="-91.37911" XOffset="-0.0" YOffset="4.5499997" Custom="True" Visible="True" Rotation="0.0" RotationOverride="False" ParentRotation="0" Alignment="Center">
                    <Font ColorChanged="False" Color="ARGB(255,0,0,0)" Bold="False" Size="8" Underline="False" Family="Verdana" Italic="False" FontChanged="False"/>
                    <TextLines>First Floor</TextLines>
                </NameLabel>
                <Lines>
                    <Line1 ArcHeight="-0.0" Guid="23e26249-5fae-459a-919b-f3086e8f878c" Width="3" Color="ARGB(255,0,0,0)" EndCap="Flat" HasUserRotation="True" StartCap="Flat" DashStyle="Solid">
                        <ArcHandle Width="1" LocationX="-43.75" LocationY="-3.8247463E-6"/>
                        <Label Y="8.719906" TackedTo="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" XOffset="0.0" Alignment="Center" X="-43.75" Visible="True" RotationOverride="False" ParentRotation="0" YOffset="0.0" Rotation="0">
                            <Font ColorChanged="False" Color="ARGB(255,0,0,0)" Bold="False" Size="6" Underline="False" Family="Verdana" Italic="False" FontChanged="False"/>
                            <TextLines>12.5 '</TextLines>
                        </Label>
                        <Start LocationX="0.0" LocationY="0.0"/>
                        <End LocationX="-87.5" LocationY="-7.6494925E-6"/>
                    </Line1>
                    <Line2 ArcHeight="-0.0" Guid="f2fbd11d-5b75-40ac-969b-f33b6c0eaa02" Width="3" Color="ARGB(255,0,0,0)" EndCap="Flat" HasUserRotation="True" StartCap="Flat" DashStyle="Solid">
                        <ArcHandle Width="1" LocationX="-87.5" LocationY="-99.750015"/>
                        <Label Y="-99.75" TackedTo="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" XOffset="0.0" Alignment="Center" X="-96.25861" Visible="True" RotationOverride="False" ParentRotation="0" YOffset="0.0" Rotation="0">
                            <Font ColorChanged="False" Color="ARGB(255,0,0,0)" Bold="False" Size="6" Underline="False" Family="Verdana" Italic="False" FontChanged="False"/>
                            <TextLines>28.5 '</TextLines>
                        </Label>
                        <Start LocationX="-87.5" LocationY="-7.6494925E-6"/>
                        <End LocationX="-87.5" LocationY="-199.50002"/>
                    </Line2>
....
...
..
.
```

Comment: It would be easier to convert the XML to SVG via xslt and display that SVG directly wouldn't it?

Comment: The report I have to input the image file into doesn't accept SVG. Only jpg, png or gif unfortunately. Thank you, but any other suggestions?

Comment: Convert to SVG then convert to png via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/convert-svg-to-image-jpeg-png-etc-in-the-browser

Comment: I'll try that out Robert, thank you.

Comment: @RobertLongson, I'm struggling greatly to find tutorials on how to convert my (client-side) XML to SVG. My XML is shown above.... any thoughts? Thank you

Comment: I already suggested XSLT as a technology and you have it in the question's tags. Use that.