# Lines drawn with raphael.js not being saved to png

Tags: jquery, raphael, html2canvas

I have a network design tool which allows to click and drag images to the div and also to draw lines on the div. I used the raphael.js library to draw on the div.

When drawing: [image]

When I click on the download button: [image]

As you can see, the lines are not being saved.

The codes:

**HTML**

```
<!--The button-->
<div id="menu2">
    <span style="color:white; margin-bottom:-20px; z-index:3; font-family:Montserrat; font-size:11px; margin-top: 5px; position:absolute; margin-left:5px;">Download</span>

    <div id="menu_button2" class="btnSave" onClick="btn()"
         style="margin-left:5px; width:65%; height:8%; margin-top:20px; border-radius:7px;">
        <img style="margin-left:12px; margin-top:9px;" src="image/save-file.png" title="Save" width="55%"/>
    </div>
</div>

<!--The div-->
<div class="col" id="droppable" style="background-color: white;">
</div>
```

**JQuery Function**

```
function btn() {
            html2canvas($("#droppable"), {
                onrendered: function (div) {
                    // canvas is the final rendered <canvas> element
                    var myImage = div.toDataURL("image/png");
                    window.open(myImage);
                }
            });
        }
```

**The raphael.js function**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('input[type="checkbox"][name="check"]').change(function() {
                // proceed only when checked
                if(this.checked) {
                    drawLine();
                }
            });
        });

        function drawLine() {

            var linewidth = $("#width" ).val();
            var color = $("#background").val();

            function Line(startX, startY, endX, endY, raphael) {
                var start = {
                    x: startX,
                    y: startY
                };
                var end = {
                    x: endX,
                    y: endY
                };
                var getPath = function () {
                    return "M" + start.x + " " + start.y + " L" + end.x + " " + end.y;
                };


                var redraw = function () {
                    node.attr("path", getPath());
                }

                var node = raphael.path(getPath());

                node.attr("stroke-width", linewidth); //sets the width of the line
                node.attr("stroke", color);

                //sets the color of the line

                return {
                    updateStart: function (x, y) {
                        start.x = x;
                        start.y = y;
                        redraw();
                        return this;
                    },
                    updateEnd: function (x, y) {
                        end.x = x;
                        end.y = y;
                        redraw();
                        return this;
                    }
                };
            };


            $(document).ready(function () {
                var paper = Raphael("droppable", 1280, 470, 0, 0);
                $("#droppable").mousedown(
                        function (e) {
                            x = e.offsetX;
                            y = e.offsetY;
                            line = Line(x, y, x, y, paper);
                            $("#droppable").bind('mousemove', function (e) {
                                x = e.offsetX;
                                y = e.offsetY;
                                line.updateEnd(x, y);
                            });

                        });

                $("#droppable").mouseup(
                        function (e) {
                            $("#droppable").unbind('mousemove');
                        });
            });
        }
```

Any idea why this is happening? Any insight will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hard to tell from that info. Best guess would be that the the line is on a different div/svg that isn't being saved.

Comment: Nope they are on the same div which is #droppable.

Answer (score 0):

Raphael is intended to draw only vector graphics, and canvas can contain raster graphics only. Lines drawn with Raphael won't appear on canvas and therefore won't be saved with `.toDataURL` method.

If your output format is PNG you should to use a library for drawing specially on canvas. My recommendation is [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) since all graphic objects are stored as objects.

Comment: Or you could possibly use canvg to convert it first, eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/convert-svg-to-image-jpeg-png-etc-in-the-browser

Comment: I'm not using canvas. I'm drawing on the Div. Okay thanks I'll try it.

Comment: @ManishaSinghSanoo Did you find the solution? I'm also stuck at the same thing.