# I only have SVG path in html, I need to get the image as png or any other extension how can I do so?

Tags: svg

I want to convert svg to .png image but I do not have the image, I only have it as html svg tag with a path

Comment: where is your path

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/convert-svg-to-image-jpeg-png-etc-in-the-browser