# Convert HTML which contains SVG elements to image file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, html2canvas

I'm trying to convert an html code to image file (png, jpg, whatever). However, all approach that I tried doesn't work because my HTML code has SVG elements like that:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" viewBox="0 0 150.000000 150.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" class="img30p icon-main-color">
    <g transform="translate(0.000000,150.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" fill="#000000" stroke="none">
    <path d="M572 1430 c-233 -62 -408 -227 -490 -459 -24 -69 -27 -89 -27 -221 0 -132 3 -152 27 -221 39 -110 92 -194 172 -275 81 -80 165 -133 275 -172 69 -24 89 -27 221 -27 132 0 152 3 221 27 110 39 194 92 275 172 80 81 133 165 172 275 24 69 27 89 27 221 0 132 -3 152 -27 221 -39 110 -92 194 -172 275 -81 81 -166 134 -275 171 -105 36 -291 42 -399 13z m376 -83 c100 -35 171 -80 245 -154 76 -76 126 -158 158 -255 20 -60 24 -94 24 -188 0 -94 -4 -128 -24 -188 -32 -97 -82 -179 -158 -255 -73 -74 -144 -119 -245 -155 -63 -23 -89 -26 -193 -27 -100 0 -132 4 -193 24 -368 121 -544 530 -377 876 79 164 240 294 421 340 92 23 250 15 342 -18z"></path>
    <path d="M873 788 l-183 -183 -100 100 c-83 83 -103 98 -117 89 -48 -30 -44 -38 90 -171 l127 -128 212 212 212 212 -24 26 c-13 14 -26 25 -29 25 -3 0 -88 -82 -188 -182z"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I tried to use Html2Canvas and doesn't worked:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js"></script>
<script>

$(function(){
  $('#save_image_locally').click(function(){
        html2canvas($('#imagesave'), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg").replace("image/jpeg", "image/octet-stream");
                a.download = 'test.jpg';
                a.click();
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="imagesave" style="width: 200px">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" viewBox="0 0 150.000000 150.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" class="img30p icon-main-color">
    <g transform="translate(0.000000,150.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" fill="#000000" stroke="none">
    <path d="M572 1430 c-233 -62 -408 -227 -490 -459 -24 -69 -27 -89 -27 -221 0 -132 3 -152 27 -221 39 -110 92 -194 172 -275 81 -80 165 -133 275 -172 69 -24 89 -27 221 -27 132 0 152 3 221 27 110 39 194 92 275 172 80 81 133 165 172 275 24 69 27 89 27 221 0 132 -3 152 -27 221 -39 110 -92 194 -172 275 -81 81 -166 134 -275 171 -105 36 -291 42 -399 13z m376 -83 c100 -35 171 -80 245 -154 76 -76 126 -158 158 -255 20 -60 24 -94 24 -188 0 -94 -4 -128 -24 -188 -32 -97 -82 -179 -158 -255 -73 -74 -144 -119 -245 -155 -63 -23 -89 -26 -193 -27 -100 0 -132 4 -193 24 -368 121 -544 530 -377 876 79 164 240 294 421 340 92 23 250 15 342 -18z"></path>
    <path d="M873 788 l-183 -183 -100 100 c-83 83 -103 98 -117 89 -48 -30 -44 -38 90 -171 l127 -128 212 212 212 212 -24 26 c-13 14 -26 25 -29 25 -3 0 -88 -82 -188 -182z"></path>
    </g>
    </svg>
</div>

<input type="button" id="save_image_locally" value="click"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have any idea to make it work? Or some approach which uses PHP? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert SVG to image (JPEG, PNG, etc.) in the browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/convert-svg-to-image-jpeg-png-etc-in-the-browser)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert SVG to image is kind of [troublesome](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/95). The usual strategy is first convert the SVG to a canvas element, and then to the image file.

To do that, you will need the [canvg library](https://github.com/gabelerner/canvg).

Let's begin. First of all, you need to serialiaze your SVG

```
var svgImage = $('#imagesave').children('svg')[0];
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var str = serializer.serializeToString(svgImage);
```

Then, create a canvas and insert it into the DOM

```
var $canvas = $('<canvas/>');
$canvas.attr('width', '150px;')
$canvas.attr('height', '150px;')
$canvas.appendTo('body');
```

Now, "paint" the canvas with your SVG using **canvg**

```
canvg($canvas.get(0), str);
```

And then, you save the image

```
html2canvas($canvas, {
  onrendered: function (canvas) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = canvas.toDataURL();
    a.download = 'test.png';
    a.click();
    $canvas.remove(); //removes canvas from body
  }
});
```

You can see this altogether in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o3efwtkh/)

Comment: jsFiddle fixed, the url of some libs were broken.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create the different file types you need out of your svg code by doing this:

You can use [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/)'s export feature to create a .png file by first importing your svg code into Inkscape. Then, using a program like *Paint*, open your newly created .png file and save a copy as .jpg. Now you have two image files ready to to be saved.

I'm not sure of any other way to save a svg graphic through a webpage as multiple file types. This is a good idea though, so maybe there is some existing opensource out there.