# Svg with image tag to png using javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I am working on a PHP script in which I will need to convert SVG to png and to save CPU usage and server load it's better to do the conversion in the client site(Browser) and this is possible with only Javascript.
Html code :

```
    <div>
 <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="800" height="420" id="svg"><image height="420" width="800" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/76/Tabby_cat-hello.jpg" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)" class="draggable" type="staticimg" id="1465449556528" ></image> </svg>
    <a id='imgId'>Save</a>
</div>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Javascript code:

```
    var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
var svg_xml = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg),
    blob = new Blob([svg_xml], {type:'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'}),
    url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

var img = new Image();
img.width = 730;
img.height = 300;
img.onload = function(){
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = 730;
    canvas.height = 300;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 730, 300);

    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    var canvasdata = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    var a = document.getElementById('imgId');
    a.download = "export_" + Date.now() + ".png";
    a.href=canvasdata;   
}
img.src = url
```

the svg works just find but i cant convert to png.
JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/vyLtxgh4/6/

Comment: What I understand from your code sample is that you're trying to convert png to png?

Comment: @IgweKalu Im trying to convert the svg to png

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but the upper html code snippet does not convert SVG to PNG. It just embeds a PNG image into an SVG image. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_Image_Tag 
I don't see where in the lower code snippet you try to do the conversion. What you need to do abstractly is rasterizing a rendered SVG. See this question for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/convert-svg-to-image-jpeg-png-etc-in-the-browser

Comment: @Thomas When trying to convert svg to canvas it works perfect but the problem is when i try to convert canvas to png  because the svg has external images (Using the method included in the question)

Comment: @thomas please check this : http://jsfiddle.net/vyLtxgh4/6/

Comment: @IgweKalu Please check the update!

Comment: @BelatarYassine Yep, the second jsfiddle example works. In the first example though, I don't see where you try to actually do the conversion?

Comment: @Thomas it was just an error the second jsfiddle doesn't convert SVG to png I only see a blank image when downloading. It is because I use external images in the main SVG . What should I do to solve this issue ?

Comment: `img` element can't load external resources, so you need to append a dataURI version of your external image insise the markup. There is duplicate question I already answered somewhere (can't find it rn) and I wrote [this script](https://github.com/Kaiido/SVG2Bitmap) (still in alpha release) which does handle this case if the external images are served with correct cross-origin headers. Also note that some UAs has trouble with xlink in blobs, better hse a plain dataUri version.

Comment: @Kaiido I included you script but don't know how to use it . SVG2Bitmap(sourceElement, [receiver] [, {optionalParameters}]); please can you explain more ?

Comment: SourceElement is either an svg element, either an object element or an iframe pointing to an svg file. Receiver is either null, in this case the source element is replaced with the canvas one, an img element where the dataUrl of the canvas willl be passed, or a callback function with the resulting canvas passed as first parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Building on top of your code, I came up with the following snippets.**

- see **HTML** and **JavaScript** code snippets below
- [the same code in **jsFiddle** can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/4ct5uwc3/)
- the same code in **stackoverflow-embedded snippets** can be found at the end (scroll down)

The solution is not perfect, but I think it can serve as starting point for you to continue development.

---

**HTML**

*First*, I am using an additional javascript library that needs to be loaded. It can be found here: [Javascript SVG parser and renderer on Canvas](https://github.com/gabelerner/canvg)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gabelerner.github.io/canvg/canvg.js"></script>
```

Then your original code follows with some reformatting and an additional canvas element.

```
<div>
    <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="800" height="420" id="svg">
        <image height="420" width="800" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/76/Tabby_cat-hello.jpg" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)" class="draggable" type="staticimg" id="1465449556528" ></image> 
    </svg>
    <a id="imgId" download="Canvas.png" href="#">Save</a>
</div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="730px" height="300px"></canvas>
```

---

**JavaScript**

*Second*, in the JavaScript part I use the loaded `canvg.js` library to write the serialized svg code to the canvas. The function `downloadCanvas()` is then attached as a click event listener on the `imgId` hyperlink element. So, the potentially expensive conversion to a data url string is only done on demand (=click).

```
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
var svg_xml = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg);
svg.remove();

// write serialized svg to canvas
canvg('canvas', svg_xml, {useCORS: true});

// create canvas data on demand
function downloadCanvas() {
    this.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
};
document.getElementById('imgId').addEventListener('click', downloadCanvas, false);
```

---

**Stackoverflow Snippet**

```js
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
var svg_xml = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg);
svg.remove();

canvg('canvas', svg_xml, {
  useCORS: true
});

function downloadCanvas() {
  this.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
};
document.getElementById('imgId').addEventListener('click', downloadCanvas, false);
```

```html
<script src="http://gabelerner.github.io/canvg/canvg.js"></script>
<div>
  <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="800" height="420" id="svg">
    <image height="420" width="800" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/76/Tabby_cat-hello.jpg" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)" class="draggable" type="staticimg" id="1465449556528"></image>
  </svg>
  <a id="imgId" download="Canvas.png" href="#">Save</a>
</div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="730px" height="300px"></canvas>
```