# send highcharts images to server using ajax call without phantomjs use

Tags: javascript, json, image, highcharts

I need to export multiple charts images to the server with the ajax call and form a pdf in the backend. I dont want to use phantomjs , it has to be a client side solution.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!

Answer (score 1):

PhantomJS is used to convert the highcharts svg into an image, there is technically no image displayed on the front end, but an svg.  You can send that svg to the back end, but then you will need a way to put that svg into a pdf.

Comment: thanks . but the idea is we need to generate a pdf with multiple highcharts in it. So we are thinking to generate them on front end and somehow send them to the server as images. anything you can suggest me on that?

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/convert-svg-to-image-jpeg-png-etc-in-the-browser