# Convert SVG Ellipse to Image in Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg, html5-canvas

Hey guys I have got the following SVG with Ellipse in it:

```
     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="16" height="16">
          <ellipse cx="50%" cy="50%" rx="50%" ry="50%" fill="#fefefe"></ellipse>
        </svg>
```

I want to convert the above one (which is in string format btw) into an Image so that I can then use it on canvas using putImageData. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/convert-svg-to-image-jpeg-png-etc-in-the-browser

Comment: @VinodLouis Thanks but those answers require some use of libraries. I have to do it in just Vanilla JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a `<canvas>` element does not allow for `<svg>` to be drawn onto it directly, you'll have to "convert" it to an `<img>` first.

This is a rather simple process involving a (short) number of steps:

Place the SVG into an image.
This can be done by creating an `<img>` and setting its `.src` to a data-url containing the SVG.

```
var svg = document.querySelector('svg'),
    img = document.createElement('img');

img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,' + svg.outerHTML;
```

This may be a little more complicated if the SVG will contain characters you need to escape (especially a `#` can be nasty).

Place the image onto the canvas.
A canvas has a [`context`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) which allows for `<img>` (and others, but not `<svg>`) to be drawn into it.

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//  now that we have the SVG nicely embedded in an image, we can
//  use the image to size the canvas
canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;

//  and draw the image onto the canvas (in the top/left corder) 
//  using the context 
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

[a working fiddle for you to play with](https://jsfiddle.net/foozle/ur1ov8q5/)

---

As the question itself is tagged with `svg-filters` and these *will* require the `#`, you may want to rewrite the assignment of `img.src` to something like:

```
img.src = svg.outerHTML.replace(/#/g, '%23');
```