# Convert d3 map to high resolution image

Tags: d3.js, svg

So far I've explored two methods, but haven't been succcessful

1. converting my d3 image to SVG via SVG crowbar, but it left out dots on my map and also wasn't the high resolution image conversion I was looking for.
2. the following snippet of code, dies without any message

   ```
   d3.select("#download").on("click", function () {
        d3.select("#map_container")
           .attr("href", 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + btoa(d3.select("#map_container").html()))
           .attr("download", "map.jpeg")
   });
   ```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There are some alternative approaches in this answer:

[Convert SVG to image (JPEG, PNG, etc.) in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/convert-svg-to-image-jpeg-png-etc-in-the-browser)