# Combine SVG with underlying JPEG into canvas in js

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas

is there a way to combine an SVG which has been placed over an image into a new image. I think I have to write both on an canvas element but I'm not sure if this actually would work. Neither how.

Maybe this image helps to clarify what I'm trying to achive. The red dashed element would be the svg.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: yes, writing them on canvas would seem to be the way to go.

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/convert-svg-to-image-jpeg-png-etc-in-the-browser