# How to download PNG image using s3 URL to it's SVG in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, canvg

I want to download as a PNG image using amazon s3 url which is a svg.
What's the ideal way to convert this SVG to PNG and download it?

s3 URL: https://eocs-icons.s3.amazonaws.com/withText/2022/clean.svg

Comment: so you want to save it as png?

Comment: @Apostolos yes. Any useful link for reference would be really helpful.

Comment: you can't just download an SVG *as a PNG* and expect some majicks to convert it for you - The ideal way is to convert it

Comment: a "google" search for "convert SVG to PNG in javascript" yielded [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74026755/5053002) on stack overflow - I've linked to the answer posted 7 DAYS ago on this 10+ year old question - so, don't be put off by the age of the question

Comment: to be honest, if you hadnt commented the  7 days vs 10+ years i may have not opened the link but i was curious enough! great answer by this guy!

Comment: @JaromandaX I failed to understand the correct usage of s3 url. Where do I have to use it in the code?

Comment: Why can't you use the svg? Is your question maybe "how can I render an svg in React"?

Comment: oh, you'd have to download the SVG using the "SVG url" and fetch or XMLHttpRequest of course