# Create static png from svg without Anti-aliasing, with or without canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, svg, antialiasing

**What I want**

I want to take a vector SVG image and create a raster png from it without Anti-aliasing. The svg will be dynamically generated based on user input (text, bold, font-family). png is preferred, but other raster formats can be accepted.

**What I am trying**

```
var svg = '<svg><g><text>Hello World</text></g></svg>';
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.setAttribute('src','data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(svg_static_data) );
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    ctx.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    static_image = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
};
```

The svg here is very simple simply for demonstration. Here, I turn the svg into a canvas element, and turn the canvas element into an image. When that resulted in Anti-aliasing, the only configuration I found that might help was `imageSmoothingEnabled`, however I am still getting Anti-aliasing, likely because that configuration is for elements drawn with canvas itself. I have also tried placing that configuration above `drawImage`, but no luck.

**What I need**

A function to turn a dynamic non-animated SVG, that may contain many elements and attributes, including curved text, into a raster image that is at least mostly identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imageSmoothingEnabled` do only apply to images, but only when the image source is drawn scaled.

However, the problem in this case is that the SVG image is anti-aliased *internally* when rasterized *before* your `onload` handler kicks in, so when you draw it to canvas it is already anti-aliased - there is nothing you can do to turn this off except by manually parsing and rendering the SVG (which is not a small project).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question, while slightly different, explains why you can't use the drawImage method on SVGs. Hope you find it helpful: [Is there an equivalent of canvas's toDataURL method for SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173048/is-there-an-equivalent-of-canvass-todataurl-method-for-svg)

Answer (score 0):

Using a clever filter technique on the alpha channel ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35486696/1869660)), you can "un-alias" all elements in your SVG before rendering it to the canvas. Just insert this at the top of the `<svg>` element:

```
<defs>
    <filter id="crispify">
        <feComponentTransfer>
            <feFuncA type="discrete" tableValues="0 1"/>
        </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
</defs>
<style>
    svg * {
        filter: url('#crispify');
    }
</style>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uqfgs477/1

Works in Chrome and Edge, not in Firefox.