# Get chart SVG from vega chart

Tags: javascript, svg, char, vega

I am migrating from vega 2.x to 5.13.0 version. I am trying to generate chart SVG, so I can use as per my requirement. For that I am using toSVG(). While using that either success or catch method both are not firing.

```
      var view = new vega.View(vega.parse(chartJson), {renderer: 'none'});
      view.toSVG().then(function (svg) {
        console.log(svg)
      }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err)
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do the below:

```js
var _v = new vega.View(vega.parse(spec))...

_v.toSVG()
  .then(svgString => {
      const filename = 'chart.svg';
      const url = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + encodeURIComponent(svgString);
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.setAttribute('href', url);
      link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
      link.setAttribute('download', filename);
      link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
    })
```

This will download the SVG. Adapted from a different [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16604302/514874) (for mime type) and Vega [test cases](https://github.com/vega/vega/blob/0b64d673d86942ba96a559d6b5f4eb87c83e4563/packages/vega-typings/tests/runtime/index.ts#L59) (for handling `toSVG()` promise).